# Top bar not showing when i start Geany in GNOME

Tags: gnome3, geany

When i start Geany in GNOME both the top and title bar disappear leaving just the ide, also when i try to move the window to break this it does not let me. i have already tried reinstalling the editor with apt-get and looking through the gnome tweaks tool but neither have worked.[image: here is a screen shot of my whole screen]  i am running Debian.

Comment: Is Geany in fullscreen mode? Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/385277/how-to-get-out-of-fullscreen-mode

Comment: Try alt+v to display the view menu and check the options

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
F11 was the solution.